# Mozilla developer network - What does the question mark refer to?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Under [`Properties->"onreadystatechange"->Type:Function?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#Properties),

```
Attribute           Type       Description
------------------------------------------
onreadystatechange  Function?  [...]
                            ^
```

What does the `?` mean?

Comment: I've always assumed these `?`s on _MDN_ are to show the writer is uncertain of the _type_ and it shouldn't be taken as fact.

Comment: But i guess that will be documented somewhere. Shouldn't it be?

Comment: I think it denotes a callback that may be a function declaration (`Function function`) or function expression (anonymous or labeled). It should be documented, I would think. Or hope.

Comment: If you look in the history, [this edit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest$revision/14341) suggests at one point it used to differ with it's reference to `nsIDOMEventListener`. So the `?` may do nothing except show there may be multiple meanings, or it may be a literal question as in *What goes here?*

Comment: it might mean Nullable .. see the type of `responseXML` is `Document?`  with similar description.."The response to the request as a DOM Document object, or `null` if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or cannot be parsed as XML or HTML. "

Comment: Here are the [two edits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest$compare?to=14396&from=14395) where the change was made. No note as to the reasoning, of course.

Comment: Looks to me that the source of the various question marks is not q question to put to the Mozilla Developer Network question but rather stems from the W3C documentation. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#xmlhttprequest (Although I do not see a "?" in front of `onreadystatechange` on W3C.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think it means the value can be null.

Comment: I think so too. But not sure.

Comment: It certainly should be documented somewhere. This seems more like a comment in lieu of an answer (and a reasonable assumption). Still, without knowing the true intention, how is it an answer?